# Replacing any single digit in string with leading 0 in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I have a variable with the values as t14-1-1, t14-1-1A, t14-2-1-1, t14-2-4-15A, etc as mentioned in the cards statement below.

What i need is to pad any single digit in the string with a leading 0, as we do it with sas format z2.

```
data test01;
    input have $40.;

    want02=prxchange('s/(^|-)\d($|-)*/\10\2/',-1,strip(have));
    want03=prxchange('s/(^|-)\d($|-)*(.+)/\10\2/',-1,strip(have));

    cards;
    t14-1-1
    t14-1-1A
    t14-2-1-1
    t14-2-1-1A
    t14-2-4-15A
    t14-2-4-15B
    t14-2-4-16
    t14-2-4-17
    t14-2-4-17A
    t14-2-4-17B
    l16-2-9-1-1
    l16-2-9-2-1
    l16-2-9-2-2
    ;
run;
```

What I need is the following:

```
t14-01-01
t14-01-01A
t14-02-01-01
t14-02-01-01A
t14-02-04-15A
t14-02-04-15B
t14-02-04-16
t14-02-04-17
t14-02-04-17A
t14-02-04-17B
l16-02-09-01-01
l16-02-09-02-01
l16-02-09-02-02
```

I know I have a way of doing this with array and scan, length and tranward functions. I was just wondering if this can be done through prxchange (regular expression) in a few steps with less complexity.

I have tried a lot with different permutation and combinations with no luck.

Thanks for the help in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if SAS regex flavour supports lookarround, but, if it does, this should do the job:

- search: `(?<=-)(\d)(?!\d)`
- replace: `0$1`

Where:

- `(?<=-)` is a lookbehind that make sure we have a dash before
- `(\d)` is a single digit captured in group 1
- `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that make sure we have not digit after

Comment: Yep, they do.  `want02=prxchange('s/(?<=-)(\d)(?!\d)/0$1/',-1,strip(have));` for example works fine.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for the confirmation too! :)